# Angular: How to display and make reactive a variable calculated from other variables?

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I am working on a balance sheet app and I am using Angular.
I have 3 variables A, B and C such that C = A + B. 
I want to display C so that it updates automatically when A or B is changed. I don't want to display just {{A + B }} because C will be used in other formulas.
**The problem is that C is not automatically updated at all.**
I ask for your help.

HTML code

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b">
<span>{{c}}</span>
```

TS Code

```
export class EtatsfinanciersComponent{
  @Input() a: number = 0;
  @Input() b: number = 15451;

  c: number = a + b

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Why *would* it be updated? Make it an [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)? Or update it in `ngOnChanges`, per e.g. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

Comment: I tried to update it in ngOnChanges but nothing happen.

Comment: So give a [mre] of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to update the value of c,

**component.ts :**

```
update(){
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
}
```

**component.html :**

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a" (change)="update()">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b" (change)="update()">
<span>{{c}}</span>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqf6fc

Comment: You can use directy `{{a+b}}` or `{{a && b? a+b:0}}`

Comment: @Eliseo Yeah that also works fine. I used a function since he wanted the result in a new variable.